# I rechecked the syntax, I am not able to view the href link in the page that is loaded

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I
 am trying to update the parameters the url can contain by giving a link
 in the loaded php, but i am not able to  view the link itself, i can 
see the table being loaded but no the link in the loaded page, may be 
something silly, but please help me. I tried in all the browsers

```html
<!Doctype html>
<table border="1" id="table">

    <p> <tr><th bgcolor="#9999FF">My repute</th>
    </p>
   </tr>
     
<?php
$c=$_GET['a'];
$d=$_GET['b'];
$tr=$_GET['j'];
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "repute system";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection_aborted(oid)
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT name,repute FROM teacher ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     
     if($c== $row['name'])
     {   
            echo "<tr><td Repute: >   " . $row["repute"]. "</tr></td>";
            $rep=$row['repute'];
     }
    }
} 
else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$some = "<a href = 'index.php?param=$tr&param1=$a&param2=$b'>Click here to go back</a>";
$conn->close();
?>
</table>
<a href="#"> <?php echo $some; ?> </a>
</html>
```

Comment: Unclear what your asking, `<td Repute: >` looks dodgy as does `</tr></td>`.  Show the rendered HTML, try `echo "<tr><td>Repute:   " . $row["repute"]. "</td></tr>";`

Comment: in last line  '<a href ="#"> <?php echo $some; ?></a>' isnt being displayed in the loaded page at all

Answer (score 0):

You have to **fix your HTML** first to solve the problem. When the HTML have problems some tags may not be rendered by the browser.

---

This line is very messy and wrong

```
<p> <tr><th bgcolor="#9999FF">My repute</th>
</p>
</tr>
```

You can fix it like this

```
<tr><th bgcolor="#9999FF"><p>My repute</p></th></tr>
```

---

This line:

```
"<tr><td Repute: >   " . $row["repute"]. "</tr></td>";
```

Become (fixed `<tr><td>...</tr><td>` in `<tr><td>...</td><tr>`):

```
"<tr><td>Repute: " . $row["repute"]. "</td></tr>";
```

---

Also you have to put your html inside `body` tag

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head> </head>
    <body>
       <!-- Add here the CODE -->
    </body>
<html>
```